# Adding information to a table in excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a code that subtracts information from one sheet and puts them in another sheet. The only problem is that the code doesn't include adding it to a table, how can I adjust my code to also include tables?

Someone know how to do both??
I would appreciate the help.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Client receipt")
    Sheets("Total").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 2) = Array(.Range("E2"), .Range("B2"))
```

Comment: Adding it to a table where? You may need to show some data, explain where this table is and what  it's name is and possibly how it is being updated. You current code is simply assigning the values from two cells in the ClientReceipt, hopefully, to the next free row in Total. P.S. Hopefully there is a ScreenUpdating = True later in the code!

Comment: The table is located in sheet "Total" it's a simple table with 2 rows (starting at A4:17 ending at B4:17) haven't given it a name. But it skips the table and adds it underneath the table to the next free row. no this is all of my code.

Comment: Then note that you will not seen a change anyway unless you switch screen updating back on. Are you wanting the current table to expand by adding a row that is still part of the table, or is there an available empty row in the table you expect to see populated by your code?

Comment: Thanks for that, I would like the current table to add a row to the next available (empty) row that is still part of the table.

Comment: I am not near a mac at present. Do they support https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listrows-add-method-excel  i.e. the ListRows.Add method.

Comment: I believe it does QHarr, most notible diference between WIN and MAC are when it boils down to DIR and the functions alike.